# Strange behaviour: if( takes boolean false

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Hi I'm writing a firebase cloud function to send an email if the user wants to receive emails. The problem is, that with userData.notifications.emails true or false, it always sends the email. With false the log shows:

```
Send Emails YES: false
```

- 

```
 if (userData?.notifications?.emails) {
       functions.logger.log('Send Emails YES: ' + userData.notifications.emails);
       admin.firestore().collection(`emails`).add({
             to: email,
             message: {
               subject: subject,
               html: text,
             }
        })
 }
 else {
      functions.logger.log('Don't send Email')
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `userData?.notifications?.emails === true`?

Comment: If `userData.notifications.emails` is the string "false" instead of the boolean `false`, it will evaluate to true

Comment: The string "false" is still truthy and will still be evaluated as true

Comment: You have an `if`, and its condition. You see the body being executed, so you know the condition is truthy. You see that concatenating it to a string gives `"false"`. Why stop there? Obviously it's not the boolean value `false`, because of previous observations - so it must be something like `"false"`, `{ toString: () => false }`, or whatever (most don't make sense because it's firebase, and kind of already obvious what it is, but that's not the point), why not add checks, or debug, and see what it actually is?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! I tried so many different things, but must have missed the easy one...
Firebase is really delivering the object as a string, so it now works with parsing it back to boolean again first.